# How to Crop face and its parts?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am building a face remake **application** from where the user **remakes** **face** by scrolling through different facial parts to make a face (basically, mix-matching eyes, nose, lips of some other person), until now I wrote an algorithm that **divides** the **facial parts** like eyes, nose from the **image** using Python's **Dlib** and **OpenCv**, but due to images being ill-captured facial features cropped aren't aligned. So when I create a database of eyes, nose, lips, and face, while remaking they aren't gonna look like a face when placed at their position.
[This is the Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrkCb.jpg)

[These are the Eyes(Titled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeRPZ.jpg)

[The Nose Cropped(tilted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmoqN.jpg)

[And Lips(tilted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F9Vu.jpg)

[This image is what I ended up to extract just the face part(**NEED ALTERNATIVE IDEA FOR THIS (%)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOghZ.jpg)

So my plan was to use this last image as the base for remaking the face.
To tackle the tilting, I applied the **face alignment** algorithm so that when I crop the **eyes** in a rectangle image is perfectly straight. But this is what I am getting:

[The face is straight but the image being tilted the **pockets of black color** are added around it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE3kw.png), now as this is unavoidable, I NEED HELP REGARDING, HOW CAN I PREPARE THE FACE WITH NO FACIAL PARTS?

NOTES:
1.) Image cropping should not crop out any part of the face.
2.) Thought of using **Grabcut** to separate face and background, but validating nearly 10,000 images, I need a higher accuracy module, Or would Grabcut be fine(NEED SUGGESTION)?

[Dont mind the smudge, but this is somewhat I need the output from the Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pegGN.jpg)